# How to change the entry id of gravity forms after submit

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

How can I change the entry id of the form in this case I want to change the form entry number to the current user id that is logged in on the site. I've tried the function below but the entry id saved on the database is not changing

```
add_filter( 'gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead', 'my_update_entry_on_form_submission', 10, 2 );
function my_update_entry_on_form_submission( $entry_id, $form ) {
    $update_entry_id = rgpost( 'input_4',true );
    
    return $update_entry_id ? $update_entry_id : $entry_id;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to change the actual entry ID to the match the user ID or that you want to update an entry previously submitted by that user?

Comment: Yes I want to change the actual entry ID using the ID of the logged in user

Comment: Hm, could you elaborate on why you want this? There may be a better solution. Matching the entry ID with the user ID is problematic.

Comment: I just want to get the forms sent by each user

Comment: I don't understand. Could you provide the full explanation for what you're trying to do?